# Primitive of an irrational function

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-functions

Does anybody know how to determine a  primitive of the function

$f(u)=\frac{u^2}{(au^4+bu^2+c)^{3/2}}$?

Here $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers and one assume that $u>0$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Wolfram alpha gives a result in terms of elliptic integrals.